# HTML email for Windows Live Mail

Tags: html, html-email, email-client, windows-live-mail

How should I modify html for email to looks correctly for Windows Live also?

Email Code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Guitar Leads Master Volume</title>
    <style>
        @media screen and (max-width: 520px) {
            .main_content {
                padding: 4% 5% !important;
                font-size: 14px !important;
            }
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 374px) {
            .main_content {
                text-align: left !important;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table style="width: 100%; border-spacing: 0; background-color: #dadada; padding: 2%;">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 0;">
            <p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin-top: 0; text-align: center; font-size: 1.125em; font-weight: bold;">
                <a target="_blank"
                   href="#">
                    Click Here to Read Online
                </a>
            </p>
            <table style="width: 100%; max-width: 700px; margin: auto; border-spacing: 0; background-color: white;">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="main_content"
                        style="padding: 5% 8%; font-size: 16px; text-align: justify; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                        <p style="font-size: 1em; margin: 3% 0px; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;"><span
                                    style="font-size: large;">Guitar Leads Master Volume ($249) and Learn2Jam ($149) - FREE - When you....</span>
                        </p>
                        <p style="font-size: 1em; margin: 3% 0;">
                            Nunc in metus in nisl luctus consectetur ac sit amet turpis. Nunc pulvinar fermentum sapien
                            ut suscipit. Sed vel tortor ornare, finibus erat non, tincidunt nibh. Fusce imperdiet,
                            tortor eget lobortis faucibus, felis ligula tempor tellus, ut gravida tellus metus ut elit.
                            Suspendisse mauris nibh, semper quis urna quis, rutrum varius sapien. Praesent ullamcorper,
                            tellus tempus accumsan tempus, metus urna ultrices metus, vel tempor mauris mauris non
                            libero. Mauris commodo rhoncus fringilla. In justo felis, congue vitae tristique nec,
                            bibendum vitae lorem. Phasellus diam dolor, facilisis a mauris sed, sodales elementum
                            ligula. Donec pulvinar accumsan felis, non tristique metus sagittis a. Praesent et egestas
                            odio. Vestibulum quis fringilla orci. Aliquam varius congue quam et hendrerit.
                        </p>
                        <p style="font-size: 1em; margin: 3% 0;">
                            Donec a venenatis orci. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
                            fames ac turpis egestas. Fusce gravida, tellus venenatis consectetur eleifend, neque lacus
                            viverra tellus, quis mollis enim turpis eu neque. Maecenas eget risus enim. Quisque
                            venenatis tincidunt sem, non vestibulum lacus. Etiam sed quam quis purus tristique tincidunt
                            eget hendrerit tortor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Maecenas bibendum sem sit amet urna
                            semper, eu condimentum ligula ornare. Nunc eget lobortis justo. Nam ac libero eu magna
                            bibendum consectetur. Ut hendrerit turpis ut scelerisque aliquam. Fusce rutrum ipsum quam,
                            rhoncus sodales elit luctus vel. Mauris porta pulvinar egestas.
                        </p>
                        <p style="font-size: 1em; margin: 3% 0;">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eu fringilla nibh.
                            Vivamus magna nunc, venenatis sit amet velit et, interdum elementum purus. Etiam gravida dui
                            quis mauris dignissim vehicula. Vestibulum vestibulum ac arcu nec maximus. Orci varius
                            natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Duis tincidunt
                            augue sit amet mauris facilisis, ac molestie leo blandit. Ut a nulla volutpat, vestibulum
                            turpis in, dignissim mi. Maecenas enim ante, iaculis aliquet venenatis eget, venenatis
                            semper nunc. Aliquam lobortis pellentesque justo, eu tempus mi dignissim eget. Aliquam velit
                            magna, bibendum eget efficitur ut, dignissim id sem. Nunc at massa felis. Vivamus nibh
                            lacus, elementum at luctus et, sollicitudin at sem. Nullam eu velit a lorem aliquet
                            pellentesque porttitor et diam. Suspendisse porta justo vitae tempus eleifend. Curabitur
                            metus sapien, fermentum sed tincidunt et, aliquet ut elit. Vivamus nec tincidunt sem, eget
                            cursus ex.
                        </p>
                        <p style="font-size: 1em; margin: 3% 0 0 0; text-align: center;">
                            <a href="#">
                                Click here if you wish to unsubscribe permanently from our system.
                            </a>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-size: 0; padding: 2% 0; text-align: center; background-color: black;"></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I am sending HTML email to customers, and for all email clients it looks perfectly fine, but for customers who are using Windows Live Mail it's blank. When somebody try to resent it to me, it look on my client (GMail) - fine.

Comment: Is it actually Windows Live Mail or just "Windows Mail"? I don't think Live is around any more. What operating system are you on? Windows XP/7/8/10?

Comment: What about changing this: `charset=windows-1252` to the more normal `charset=utf-8`

Comment: @Nathan Exactly Windows Live, because 5% from all customers use it. It not supported from 2017! But 5% from 220,000 customers is 11,000, and this is a HUGE number. so I should to figure out what is going on... And what about charset, I agree I will change it, but issue not in it, I am pretty sure that should be some "if" in code. But after research a didn't find anything that help me

Comment: how can it just be 'blank' - can you put up a screenshot? And a screenshot of what it should look like? When it's 'blank', cna you still select the text (is it a colour issue?)?

Comment: @Nathan https://ibb.co/Y2sTWWH

Comment: Can you set the font color on one of the p's or td's, and see if it shows up? ie. `<p style="color:#000000;">text</p>`